# How does QFileSystemWatcher determines if a file is modified?

Tags: qt

I am trying to watch a log file using `QFileSystemWatcher` but `fileChanged` signal is not consistently emitted every time the log file is modified. Any idea how `QFileSystemWatcher` determines if a file is modified (on windows)?

Comment: There is no clear documentation on this. I would say whenever your filesystem changes the timestamp. When you want to know more look at the source code I would guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QFileSystemWatcher'`s performance is entirely dependent on what the underlying platform provides. There are in general absolutely no guarantees that if one process is writing to a file, some other process will see these changes immediately. The behavior of `QFileSystemWatcher` may be informing you of that fact. The log writing process might elect to flush the file. Depending on the platform, the semantics of a flush might be such that when `flush()` returns, other processes are guaranteed to be able to see the changes made to the file prior to `flush()`. If so, then you'd expect `QFileSystemWatcher` to notify you of the changes.

As the platforms get new features, `QFileSystemWatcher` may lag in its implementation of new filesystem notification APIs. You'd need to read its source to figure out if it supports everything your platform of choice provides in this respect.

You need to qualify `QFileSystemWatcher`'s behavior on each platform you intend to support. You may find out that explicitly polling a file information periodically may work better in some cases - again, the choice between polling and `QFileSystemWatcher` should be made on a platform-by-platform basis, as polling might incur unnecessary overheads if the watcher works OK on a given platform.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.